# Syntax for PRESOURCE call using Protocol bridge agent as source in MQFTE

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

What is the syntax for calling a shell script using presource call in mqfte protocol bridge agent as source ( Linux platform is used for FTE local as well as sftp server to which the protocol bridge agent is connecting.) Below is the error i am getting.  BFGCR0003E: A request has been made for the agent to call the command ''10.350.81.70:/testing/Sample_presrc.bat''. The agent's command path '10.350.81.70:/testing/' does not define a path to this command. Only commands whose path is on the agent's command path can be run.

Note. The script created is batch why because, the SFTP server is based on wintel platform ( where the script will be placed) but the file system is linux. And the same way the fte local on which the protocol bridge agent installed also linux platform.

Thanks,
Vasuki P

Answer (score 1):

Given the error I think your syntax is just fine. The 'command path' the error refers to maps to the 'commandPath' property of the source agent's agent.properties file documented here:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/properties.htm

The commandPath is a control which lets you restrict which commands can be run using presource calls and similar - it's a measure to help prevent the wrong applications being called, or worse someone who has compromised your MFT system being able to run any command they please.

':' is the path separator on Unix, so your commandPath is set up to run commands in a directory named '10.350.81.70', and another directory named '/testing/'. The command needs to be on a mounted filesystem on the machine the source agent is running on for a presource call. If 10.350.81.70 is the source agent's host, then alter the commandPath for that agent to '/testing' and alter the syntax of your createTransfer command to invoke '/testing/Sample_presrc.bat'